# Google Icons not quadratic, and codes don't work

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

So I'm using [Google Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) on a website I'm writing, and I have two problems:

As it says in the documentation right [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_icons#using_the_icons_in_html), you can use a span element with the correct class and just put the icon name inside, and it'll work. That's great and all, but since it apparently doesn't work in all browsers, I wanted to try the other method that's mentioned:

> For browsers that do not support ligatures, fall back to specifying the icons using numeric character references

However, I don't understand how these numeric character references work. I tried `&#xxxx;` just like in the example, with the code that's given under "Code Point" for each icon in place of the x, but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The second problem I have is that I used an icon for a button (the ligature way, since that's the only one that I got to work), and it's not quadratic. The button and icon class have no special styles applied to them, other than a color change, but for some reason the content of the button is way taller than it's wide (24 x 29.xxx if I remember correctly, with a font size of 24 px). The span inside the button is 24 x 24, but the button content is not.

[image: Example of 2. problem]

As you can see, when inspected, there's some more space underneath the plus than above it, which makes the button not quadratic as I would like it. I already tried changing the line height property to 1, and while that does reduce the space at the bottom, it's still not even. And I didn't even set the line height *anywhere* else, so I was surprised that it had any effect, because I thought 1 would be the standard.

```css
button {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button">
        <span class="material-icons">add</span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Just highlight the button text and you'll see it.

Comment: I think you just need to set the css rule `line-height: 1` on the button (edit: just read that you already tried it, sorry, but that fixed it for my browser)

Comment: @JoeLissner I just edited the code snippet, and for me (Safari on Mac, if that makes a difference) that reduces the size by about two pixels, but its still 24 x 27 and not how it's supposed to be.

Comment: to make an element quadratic use: `aspect-ratio: 1/1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an element as square you can use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;`
To center the icon within the button you can use flexbox:

```css
/* makes the button square */
button {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

/* cenetrs the icon horizontally and vertically */
button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Body -->
<button type="button">
  <span class="material-icons">add</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @tacoshy seems to cover the first part of your question.

For the second part - using a code insted of the name of an icon - you need to use exactly the layout given in the google documentation. Note that they have an x after the # - this indicates to the HTML 'special characters' system (ie starting with an ampersand) that the following code is in hexadecimal.

So for the add sign you need to use: `&#xe145;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can only mark one answer as the most helpful, but you're still awesome.